# Ошибка с библиотекой brawlstars.py при вводе команды

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, brawlstars.py

Есть код:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ui import View, Button
from discord.utils import get
from discord import *
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import brawlstars as bs

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

client = bs.Client("Developer token")

@bot.command()
async def pstat(ctx, playertag):
    async with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    player = client.get_player(playertag)
    battles = client.get_player_battlelog(playertag)
    club = client.get_club(player.club.tag)

    em = discord.Embed(title="Статистика игрока: ", description=f"Никнэйм игрока: {player.name}"
                                                                f"\nТрофеи игрока: {player.trophies}"
                                                                f"\nОдиночных побед в столкновении: {player.solo_victories}"
                                                                f"\nПарных побед в столкновении: {player.duo_victories}"
                                                                f"\nПобед в режимах 3 на 3: {player.team_victories}"
                                                                f"\nКлан игрока: {club.name}"
                                                                f"\nТэг клана игрока: {player.club.tag}")
    em.add_field(name="Данные последнего боя игрока: ", value=f"Игровой режим: {battles[0].battle.mode}")

    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command()
async def cstat(ctx, clantag):
    async  with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    club = client.get_club(clantag)
    members = client.get_club_members(clantag)
    type = club.type
    if(type == "open"):
        type = "открытый"
    else:
        if(type == "close"):
            type = "закрытый"
        else:
            if(type == "by invitation"):
                type = "по приглашению"
    em = discord.Embed(title="Статистика клана: ", description=f"Название клана: {club.name}"
                                                              f"\nТрофеи клана: {club.trophies}"
                                                              f"\nТип клана: {type}"
                                                              f"\nТрофеи для вступления в клан: {club.required_trophies}",
                       )
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command()
async def clist(ctx, clantag):
    async  with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    club = client.get_club(clantag)
    members = client.get_club_members(clantag)
    for i in range(0, 29):
        em = discord.Embed(title="Список участников клана: ", description=f"{i+1}) Никнэйм: {members[i].name}, роль: {members[i].role}, трофеи: {members[i].trophies}")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)




bot.run("Token")
```

Но при вводе команды %clist выходит ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'nameColor'
```

Вопрос - как исправить? Буду благодарен за любую помощь :)

Comment: А где вы юзаете `nameColor`? Сдаётся мне, вы привели неполный код)

Comment: @ÇℏėτᶄắɤẵÇℏėτɤᶉᶄắ Добавил полный код :)